# Constructing an unbiased estimator

Tags: sampling, unbiased-estimator, finite-population

Suppose we have a finite population $I_N$ of size $N$ on which we define a variable $\mathcal{Y}$. We also have a generic sampling design $(\mathcal{S},p)$ with first and second order inclusion probabilities $\pi_i \quad \forall i=1,\dots,N$ and $\pi_{ij} \quad \forall i \neq j$.

How can we build an unbiased estimator of the following parameter?

$$\Delta = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^N|y_i - y_j|$$

**My attempt**

I have tried building it by using general rules I have already used when building linear and quadratic estimators. Denoting $\vec{s}$ as the sample, something on the lines of

$$\hat{\Delta} = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i\in \vec{s}}\sum_{j\in \vec{s}}|y_i - y_j|c_{ij}$$

taking expected values, one has that

$$E(\hat{\Delta}) = E\left(\frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i\in \vec{s}}\sum_{j\in \vec{s}}|y_i - y_j|c_{ij} \right) = \frac{1}{N^2}E\left(\sum_{i =1}^N\sum_{j = 1}^N|y_i - y_j|c_{ij}\delta(i,\vec{s})\delta(j,\vec{s}) \right)$$

where $\delta(i,\vec{s})$ is a variable with value $1$ if the unit $i$ belongs to the sample $\vec{s}$ and 0 otherwise. Going on, we have that

$$E(\hat{\Delta}) = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i =1}^N\sum_{j = 1}^N|y_i - y_j|c_{ij}E\left(\delta(i,\vec{s})\delta(j,\vec{s}) \right) = \frac{1}{N^2}\sum_{i =1}^N\sum_{j = 1}^N|y_i - y_j|c_{ij}\pi_{ij}$$

and therefore $\hat{\Delta}$ is unbiased for $\Delta \iff c_{ij} = \frac{1}{\pi_{ij}} \quad \text{and} \quad \pi_{ij}>0 \quad \forall i \neq j$

Is this line of reasoning sound or is there some big conceptual mistake? This clearly leads me to believe that second order inclusion probabilities must be omnipresent when dealing with quadratic parameters!

**Edit**

Some clarifications. With quadratic parameters I mean parameters which are quadratic functions of the population data. Heuristically, anything that involves a double summation over all the population.

Comment: @jbowman I thought a statistic was a function of the **sample** data. $\Delta$ by itself uses data  from the entire population. Isn't this the definition of statistical parameter for a finite population?

Comment: Ah, my mistake, I didn't realize that $N$ was the population size.   I should have read more carefully.

Comment: Oh no! The mistake is mine! The subscript of $\I_n$ should have been capital $N$, thanks for pointing it out

Comment: There aren't any expressions in your post that would ordinarily be understood as "quadratic."  By "quadratic parameters" might you perhaps mean something like "non-location parameters"?  If this supposition is correct, note that if you have no information about the second-order probabilities then it's possible your sampling scheme selects an $i$ with probability $\pi_i$ and observes $y_i$ $n$ times.  (That is, $\pi_{ij}=0$ whenever $i\ne j.$) In that case it would be difficult to obtain any non-location information about the population.

Comment: @whuber Sorry for the vagueness of the term, I used it out of lack of knowledge of anything better. I have edited the question for clarifications.

Comment: Thank you.  You should know, though, that "quadratic" has a completely different meaning than "double summation."  Equating them makes your question a little confusing.